# Laravel Homestead new project error

Tags: homestead

On my Win8 machine I installed Laravel Homestead box using git. (OracleVM+Vagrant).

Homestead.yaml

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: newProject.local
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/newProject/public

databases:
    - homestead
```

I start the VM using:

```
cd Homestead
vagrant up
vagrant ssh
```

And everything works.

If I understand correctly, I still need to create a newProject in my Code/ folder.

```
cd Code
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel newProject
```

This would work if I where on a lamp server, but instead I get the following error:

```
 You are running composer with xdebug enabled. This has a major impact on runtime performance. See https://getcomposer.org/xdebug
Installing laravel/laravel (v5.2.15)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v5.2.15)
    Loading from cache

Created project in newProject
> php -r "copy('.env.example', '.env');"
> php artisan clear-compiled
PHP Warning:  require(/home/vagrant/newProject/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/vagrant/newProject/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/vagrant/newProject/artisan:0
PHP   2. require() /home/vagrant/newProject/artisan:16

Warning: require(/home/vagrant/newProject/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/vagrant/newProject/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17

Call Stack:
    0.0001     352008   1. {main}() /home/vagrant/newProject/artisan:0
    0.0001     353760   2. require('/home/vagrant/newProject/bootstrap/autoload.php') /home/vagrant/newProject/artisan:16

PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/vagrant/newProject/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:') in /home/vagrant/newProject/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/vagrant/newProject/artisan:0
PHP   2. require() /home/vagrant/newProject/artisan:16

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/vagrant/newProject/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:') in /home/vagrant/newProject/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17

Call Stack:
    0.0001     352008   1. {main}() /home/vagrant/newProject/artisan:0
    0.0001     353760   2. require('/home/vagrant/newProject/bootstrap/autoload.php') /home/vagrant/newProject/artisan:16

Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with an error


  [RuntimeException]
  Error Output: PHP Warning:  require(/home/vagrant/newProject/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/vagrant/newProject/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
  PHP Stack trace:
  PHP   1. {main}() /home/vagrant/newProject/artisan:0
  PHP   2. require() /home/vagrant/newProject/artisan:16
  PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/vagrant/newProject/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:') in /home/vagrant/newProject/bootstrap/autoload.php on line
   17
  PHP Stack trace:
  PHP   1. {main}() /home/vagrant/newProject/artisan:0
  PHP   2. require() /home/vagrant/newProject/artisan:16
```

Any ideas why would that happen? 
I tried to cp a working project and still get the required error. 
I found similar errors that had something to do with missing dependencies, but shouldn't Homestead deal with that by himself?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was a composer problem. I just tried again and it works. More about it on Laravel News: https://laravel-news.com/2016/03/may-need-update-composer-json-file/